# Destructing an object of a class inheriting from QObject

Tags: c++, memory-management, qt4

I have a class inheriting from QObject, and it overrides the eventFilter() method. It looks something like this:

```
struct A
{
  void DoSomething()
  {
  }
};

struct B : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  B( QObject *parent, A &a_ ) ) : QObject( parent ), a( a_ )
  {
  }

  bool eventFilter( QObject * watched, QEvent * event )
  {
    if ( QEvent::FocusOut == event->type() )
    {
      a.DoSomething();
      return true;
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter( watched, event );
  }

  A &a;
};
```

This is just simplified example. Now in my code, the object of type A (that gets passed to the constructor of object of type B) gets destroyed before the qt starts destroying objects inheriting from QObject.

Is there a way to tell qt to release the object of type B before? I can not simply delete it, because the qt will try to use it and release it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since B is an event filter, you would need to find the object (or objects) that it is filtering on and remove it from those objects.  At that point, you should be able to delete B without any problem.  When a QObject-derived class is deleted, Qt stops tracking it and won't try to delete it later.

Answer (score 0):

As the object `B` requires `A` to live, it would be fair if it could keep it alive, i.e. manage it lifetime (either directly or via a shared pointer). If `A` is itself a `QObject`, you could use the Qt's concept of [object trees](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.4/objecttrees.html) that will manage it automatically. If it is not, you could create a separate QObject managing `A`'s lifetime and make it `B`'s child.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is Qt-specific? It looks like you are storing **a reference to the A object** in your class instead of copying A in the constructor. This is generally a source of problems.

Can't you just copy the passed A to an internal A (not A&)? This is the typical design.

Comment: I can not copy object of type A, because the above is just a simplified example. The real class type A inherits from a pure base class and is passed to object of type B through the reference to the base class.

Comment: It is not always a source of problems, storing a reference is a good option in many cases, for example for short-living objects. @VJo's case is however different, and I agree that in this case just storing a reference is not the best option, though copying is not always a good one either.